# Why does this regular expression not match?

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex: `/\s[0-9|_|-|A-Z]+$/`

Input: `"White 815-W"`

Expected Output: `"White"`

Actual Output: `"White 815-W"`

I'm expecting that `/\s[0-9|_|-|A-Z]+$/` would match `" 815-W"`, but it does not. What am I missing?

```js
console.log("White 815-W".replace(/\s[0-9|_|-|A-Z]+$/, ''))
```

Comment: You can't use an `|` pipe in a character class, like that. It represents the character. `-` must be between a range or escaped, like `\-`, or at the beginning or end of the character class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the `|` or operators in your char class also with the range of `-`  That needs to be at the start.

```js
console.log("White 815-W".replace(/\s[-0-9_A-Z]+$/, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex you are looking for is `/\s[0-9]+-[A-Z]+$/`

`\s` will match any white space
`[0-9]+` will match 1 or more digits
`-` matches the dash
`[A-Z]+` matches 1 or more uppercase letters 
`$` matches the end of the string

Your regex will match according to the following

`\s` match any white space
`[0-9|_|-|A-Z]+` 1 or more of - 1 digit, 1 | character, 1 _ character, 1 character in the range  | to | (|-|) or 1 uppercase letter

So it will match any combination of the above characters but not match anything with a '-' in it